# PostgreSQL select multiple columns of a table that is connected via a many-to-many pivot

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, many-to-many, pivot-table

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    a.account_uuid,
    a.account_no,
    a.account_group_uuid,
    a.account_scope_uuid,
    a.created_at,
    a.deleted_at,
    s.service_uuid,
    s.status,
    st.service_type,
(
    SELECT
            c.company
    FROM companies c
    WHERE a.company_owner_uuid = c.company_uuid   
)
FROM
    accounts a 
LEFT JOIN
    services s 
ON a.account_uuid = s.account_uuid 
LEFT JOIN
    service_types st 
ON s.service_type_uuid = st.service_type_uuid
WHERE
    a.deleted_at IS NULL
ORDER BY
    a.account_no
```

And I need to join and select multiple columns from a `people` table by way of a pivot table `accounts_contacts` that would have the account_uuid and a person_uuid. There are also `is_primary` and `is_active` columns on the `accounts_contacts` table and there will only be one primary at a time, so the end result would be a single first and last name. This is the idea of the query:

```
SELECT
    p.first_name, p.last_name 
FROM
    people p 
INNER JOIN
    accounts_contacts ac 
ON ac.account_uuid = a.account_uuid 
AND ac.person_uuid = p.person_uuid 
WHERE
    ac.is_primary = true 
AND ac.is_active = true
```

But not sure how to fit it into the above query. A subquery would only allow for one of the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`account_contacts` is an "association" or "junction" table.  It is not a pivot table.

The basic idea should be `join`s:

```
SELECT . . . ,
       p.first_name, p.last_name 
FROM accounts a LEFT JOIN
     services s 
     ON a.account_uuid = s.account_uuid LEFT JOIN
     service_types st 
     ON s.service_type_uuid = st.service_type_uuid LEFT JOIN
     accounts_contacts ac 
     ON ac.account_uuid = a.account_uuid LEFT JOIN
     people p
     ON ac.person_uuid = p.person_uuid AND
        ac.is_primary = true AND
        ac.is_active = true
```